# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__' (own module installed using pip)

Tags: python, reflection, pip

We have a Python 2 module which we build using `python setup.py sdist`, then deploy to a remote machine and install inside a virtualenv using `pip install mymodule.tar.gz`.

The problem is: on one machine the resulting module knows its own filepath **`__file__`**, and on another machine it doesn't. The test case is this:

`python -c "import mymodule; print(mymodule.__file__)"`

On one machine it correctly prints the full path to a location inside the virtualenv "site-packages". On another very similar machine it raises:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`

*(The machines in question are AWS EC2 nodes running Ubuntu 14.04.)*

The problem was seen when trying to resolve a path using pkg_resources by doing
`python -c  "import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('mymodule', 'migrations'))"` - this should give the full path to the module's code, but doesn't resolve properly on the problematic machine.

I can't see any differences in the shell environment, the set of packages installed by pip, or the filesystem for "mymodule" after it's been installed by pip. I've `cd`ed to an empty folder to make sure I'm not importing anything from cwd.

What differences can I investigate to trace this issue? How can I ensure that my `pip install` installs a package that knows its filepath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem for us was actually that we were installing two modules, and Python appears to have **an ordering ambiguity**. We designed and installed these two modules as separate codebases:

```
mymodule
mymodule.crazything
```

In other words, the latter is a standalone package adding a submodule to `mymodule`. This means that when the latter is compiled, it creates a virtual `mymodule` with no content.

When installing both these packages, there are then two separate `mymodule` modules installed. Which of these will be the one in use when you run `import mymodule`? As far as I can tell this is undefined by Python and it is locally consistent but not consistent across machines.

The solution for us was: don't create separate packages with submodules in. Instead we give them separate module identities that don't clash.